# Marketing Cloud Connector - changing authentication to JWT

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, jwt

In [October 2019](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_mcc_jwt_compatibility.htm&type=5) release of Marketing Cloud, Salesforce have implemented a newer way to connect the two clouds together using JWT. I wanted to know if I were to upgrade to this connection type will there be any affect on existing implementations? (losing sync'ed objects, broken API connections etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not break anything with your existing implementations. This should be seamless once you enable TSE's and then re-integrate your API User.